# how npm overrides works or how to use it

Tags: node.js, npm, kafkajs

In my nodejs application's `package.json` i have some dependency

```
"dependencies"{
   "some-v2":"git commit hash path"
}
```

Inside this dependency I am using `kafkajs` old version. To override with new version I am using `npm overrides` feature as below -

```
"overrides": {
  "kafkajs": "^2.1.0"
}
```

and I have tried this way also -

```
"overrides": {
   "some-v2": {
      "kafkajs": "^2.1.0"
   }
}
```

in both cases I am getting below error in my `docker` container when I run `npm list kafkajs`

```
my-app@1.0.0 /usr/src/my-app
`-- some-v2@2.0.1 (git ssh commit path)
`-- kafkajs@1.16.0 invalid: "^2.1.0" from node_modules/some-v2

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: kafkajs@1.16.0 /usr/src/my-app/node_modules/some-v2/node_modules /kafkajs
```

Could you please let me know how `npm overrides` works or how to use it.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: Hi Nino, I have followed the same docs

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a new dependency explicitly. In your case it will look like this:

```
"dependencies"{
   "some-v2":"git commit hash path"
   "kafkajs": "^2.1.0"
}
"overrides": {
  "kafkajs": "$kafkajs"
}
```